# auto login for spring security 2.0 RC4

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I am using grails 2.4.2 and spring security 2.0 RC4 and trying to auto login for registration purpose. The form used in `gsp` page is as follows :

```
<g:form controller="register" action="save">
username:<input type="text" name="username">
password:<input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" value="register">
</g:form>
```

and in the controller code

```
def save(){
def person = new SecUser(username:params.username, password:params.pwd , enabled: true, accountExpired: false, accountLocked: false, passwordExpired: false)

person.save()
def sec=SecUser.get(person.id)
            def role=new SecUserSecRole(secUser:SecUser.get(sec.id),secRole:SecRole.get(2))
            role.save()
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(params.user.username, params.user.password);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            redirect(controller: 'institution',action: 'index')
}
```

and have imported following

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
```

but it is not working and shows error in the  `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` as `can not invoke on null object`  please help.

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my issue for auto-login using spring security

```
def signUser = new SecUser(username: params.userEmail, password: params.userPassword)
        signUser.save()
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(signUser, null, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));                
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

`AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER")` is to be used for assigning the role to the user for auto-login, update the authority as per your requirement.

import following files for this

```
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
```

After these work, you can get `sec_user_id` using `springSecurityService.principal.id`

Answer (score 0):

You have username and password as variables in params, and you can probably use them fine to create a user, but then you try to get username and password from params.user object which is null.

modify

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(params.user.username, params.user.password);
```

to

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(params.username, params.password);
```

or probably better to

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(sec.username, sec.password);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use `springSecurityService.reauthenticate (username, password)` to reauthenticate after a user has changed his password. Should be working in the login case too.